# Kafka connect with incrementing mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have a column `id` for incrementing column in kafka-connect.
I was wondering that if I just update the `id` column to another unique id value. Does this trigger kafka-connect incrementing mode to pull data from the table?

Comment: Kafka Connect is polling on a schedule. A database event won't trigger it - as compared to Debezium/CDC solutions. Not sure that answers the question

Answer (score 1):

`kafka-connect` pulls data from the source  periodically. The default time interval is 5000 milliseconds and you can change it with the `poll.interval.ms` property. If the new value of the updated `id` is greater than the recently pulled last `id`, the row will be fetched by the connector at the next scheduled query.